# Need help to understand garbage collection in GoLang

Tags: go, garbage-collection, unsafe-pointers

I'm a little bit confused with GoLang's garbage collector.

Consider this following code, where I implement reader interface for my type T.

```
type T struct {
   header Header
   data   []*MyDataType
}

func (t *T) Read(p []byte) (int, error) {
    t.Header = *(*Header) (t.readFileHeader(p))
    t.Data = *(*[]*MyDataType) (t.readFileData(p))
}
```

wherein the reader functions I will cast the data to MyDataType using the `unsafe.Pointer` which will point to slice created with the reflect module (this is more complicated, but for the sake of the example this should be enough)

```
func (t *T) readFileData(data []byte, idx int, ...) unsafe.Pointer {
    ...
    return unsafe.Pointer(&reflect.SliceHeader{Data : uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&data[idx])), ...}) 
}
```

and If I am gonna read the data in different function

```
func (d *Dummy) foo() {
    data, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
    d.t.Read(data) <---will GC free data?
}
```

Now I'm confused if it is possible, that the GC will free loaded data from file after exiting the `foo` function. Or the data will be freed after the `d.t` is freed.

Comment: If you have a pointer to something, the GC is not going to free it. Are you experiencing a problem?

Comment: Second that - the GC is pretty reliable, so unless you're actually experiencing a problem, this seems like debugging a hypothetical and therefore unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

To understand what GC might do to your variables, first you need to know how and where Go allocates them. Here is a good reading about [escape analysis](https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2017/05/language-mechanics-on-escape-analysis.html), that is how Go compiler decides where allocate memory, between stack or heap.

Long story short, GC will free memory only if it is not referenced by your Go program.

In your example, the reference to loaded data by `data, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)` is passed to `t.Data = *(*[]*MyDataType) (t.readFileData(p))` ultimately. Therefore, they will be referenced as long as `(t *T)` struct is referenced as well. As far as I can see from your code, the loaded data will be garbage-collected along with `(t *T)`.

Answer (score -2):

According to the [reflect docs](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#SliceHeader), I've to keep a separate pointer to  `data *[]byte`, to avoid garbage collection. So the solution is to add a `referencePtr` to

```
type T struct {
   header              Header
   data                   []*MyDataType
   referencePtr      *[]byte
}
```

which will point to my data inside the Read function

```
func (t *T) Read(p []byte) (int, error) {
    t.referencePtr = &p
    t.Header = *(*Header) (t.readFileHeader(p))
    t.Data = *(*[]*MyDataType) (t.readFileData(p))
}
```

or is this unnecessary?

Comment: Edit your question for follow-ups.